# How to connect the averages of a bloxpot graph on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to connect the averages of a group and the averages of the other.

My data is:

```
structure(list(G = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), 
    T = c(19, 19, 19, 20, 18, 20, 16, 17, 17, 18, 17, 19, 17, 
    19, 17, 16, 15, 18, 15, 15, 15, 16, 15, 16, 16, 16, 15, 14, 
    16, 15, 25, 25, 25, 26, 21, 25, 23, 22, 23, 23, 24, 21, 23, 
    24, 23, 24, 22, 23, 22, 21, 22, 22, 20, 22, 22, 23, 21, 21, 
    22, 21, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 37, 37, 39, 40, 40, 39, 38, 
    39, 37, 40, 37, 38, 35, 36, 36, 36, 35, 35, 37, 38, 36, 36, 
    37, 35)), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

My input is

```
ggplot(TempFlor2, aes(x = G, y = T, 
                               color = c('WT', 'at5g01950')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)])) +
    geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0), alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, color = "black", alpha = 0.2, 
                 position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white") ,
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    labs(color = '')
```

My graph is:

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsUre.png)

And I would like to connect the blue averages and also the red averages.

I already try the modifications of [How to connect the median values of a boxplot with multiple groups using lines in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043433/how-to-connect-the-median-values-of-a-boxplot-with-multiple-groups-using-lines-i) , [Joining means on a boxplot with a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989987/joining-means-on-a-boxplot-with-a-line) and [connecting box plot means on a line graph in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65513658/connecting-box-plot-means-on-a-line-graph-in-r) but they end up not working or connecting all the dots, not differentiating blue from red.

I tried this and didnt work:

```
ggplot(TempFlor2, aes(x = G, y = T, 
                 color = c('WT', 'at5g01950')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)])) +
    geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2), alpha = 1) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c(WT = '#3CBEC3', at5g01950 = '#C3413C')) +
    geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, color = "black", alpha = 0.2, 
                 position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y = median, geom = 'line', aes(group = G, colour = G))
theme_minimal() + 
    theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white") ,
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
    labs(color = '')
```

Thank you

Comment: Please show your attempts to connect the lines. The first duplicate link looks exactly like what you are trying to do. It would be easier if your created a simple variable name for your groups other than using `c('WT', 'at5g01950')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)]` because you will need to replicate that several times.

Answer (score 0):

This it take from [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043433/how-to-connect-the-median-values-of-a-boxplot-with-multiple-groups-using-lines-i) at

```
TempFlor2 |>
  transform(colgroup = c('WT', 'at5g01950')[2 - (as.numeric(G) %% 2)]) |>
ggplot(aes(x = G, y = T, color = colgroup)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, color = "black", alpha = 0.2, 
               position = position_dodge(0.9)) + 
  stat_summary(
    fun.y = median,
    geom = 'line',
    aes(group=colgroup),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.9) #this has to be added
  ) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white") ,
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  labs(color = '')
```

[image]